# APP Stopped responding in fragment layout

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using fragment layout and when I finish saying It Stopped working.
what I need to add in this.

```
package com.example.textspeech;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;

import javax.xml.transform.Result;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import static android.app.Activity.RESULT_OK;

public class Voice extends Fragment {
//private static final int RESULT_OK = Activity.RESULT_OK;
//private static final int RESULT_OK = 0;
private TextView txtSpeechInput;
private ImageButton btnSpeak;
private final int REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT = 100;

public Voice(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.voice_to_text, container, false);
    txtSpeechInput = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txtSpeechInput);


    // hide the action bar
    //getActivity().getActionBar().hide();
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    btnSpeak = (ImageButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);
    btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //promptSpeechInput();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Say Something", 10000).show();
            promptSpeechInput();

        }

        private void promptSpeechInput() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                    RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,
                    getString(R.string.speech_prompt));
            try {
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                        getString(R.string.speech_not_supported),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }); 
}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
    case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT : {
        if (resultCode ==RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ok", 12345).show();
            ArrayList<String> result = data
                    .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            txtSpeechInput.setText(result.get(0));
        }
        break;
    }

    }
}
```

}

when I press button , google prompt open successfully but when i finish saying, App stopped responding.
please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line to the imports:

```
import static android.app.Activity.RESULT_OK;
```

There's no `RESULT_OK` field in `Fragment`, so it won't work without the import; when you're trying `Activity.RESULT_OK` you're probably forgetting to import `Activity`.

Comment: I added **import** , so it removed error. but now my App stopped working.  I edit my Question , so please help me with my new problem......Thanks

Comment: @Manojahirwar, For a new problem, please create a new question and describe the problem. For this problem, please accept my answer in case you found it helpful

Comment: yes, your answer was helpful,  but please answer my new problem